# Verify my $\epsilon$-$\delta$ limit is correct

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Have I got this correct? I understand there is no unique solution.

> Find 
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-3}$$

Given $\epsilon >0$, $x\geq R>0$
$$\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-3}-3=\frac{10}{x^2-3}\text{$<$ }\frac{3}{x}<\epsilon$$
$$x>\frac{3}{\epsilon }$$

$$\text{$\therefore$ let $R$>}\frac{3}{\epsilon}$$

$$R=\max\Big\{1,\frac{3} {\epsilon}\Big\}$$

$$\left|\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-3}-3\right|=\frac{10}{x^2}<\frac{3}{x}\text{$\leq $ }\frac{3}{R}<\epsilon$$

Comment: Is there a reason why you let $R=\max\{1,\frac3\epsilon\}$ instead of just $R=\frac3\epsilon$? There is, (in fact you better even require $R>\sqrt 3$) but you do not derive it/mention where you used it. (Hint: Your conclusion that $\frac{10}{x^2-3}<\frac3x$ is in general unjustified) - Also, you don't even tell us what you think $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-3}$ actually *is*.

Comment: This is because 10/x^(2) < 3/x is true for whenever x is greater or equal to 1.
The limit is just 3..

Comment: a) Please check that claim yourself for $x=1.001$, also check the *actual* claim $\frac{10}{x^2-3}<\frac3x$ for $x=1.8$. b) Your derivation simply never mentions "whenever $x$ is greater or equal to $1$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exposition lacks argumentation. Here's something more (possibly too) detailed:

**Problem.** Find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-3}$.

*Solution:*
I claim that the desired limit equals $3$.
To prove  that indeed $$\tag1\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-3}=3,$$ I need to show that: For any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $R\in\mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ with $x>R$ the inequality
$$\tag2\left|\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-3}-3\right|<\epsilon$$
holds. So let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We observe that
$$ \frac{3x^2+1}{x^2-3}-3=\frac{10}{x^2-3}.$$
By a suitable choice of $R$, we can ensure that this expression is between $0$ and $\frac5x$ *(The following calculation is guaranteed to succeed somehow or other with any positive numerator in place of $5$ as well; there's nothing magic in it)*. Indeed, for $x>\sqrt3$, we have $x^2-3>0$ (so that $\frac{10}{x^2-3}>0$) and $x>0$, so 
$$ \frac{10}{x^2-3}<\frac5x\iff 10x<5x^2-15\iff 10<5(x-1)^2.$$
To ensure the latter, it is sufficeint to have $(x-1)^2>2$. Hence certainly a choice of $R\ge3$ will do what we need: Then $x>R\ge3$ guarantes both $x^2-3>0$ and $(x-1)^2>2$, so 
$0<\frac{10}{x^2-3}<\frac5x $. Now if we *additionally* have that $R\ge\frac5\epsilon$, then $x>R$ implies $\frac5x<\frac5R\le\epsilon$, so that $0<\frac{10}{x^2-3}<\epsilon $, and even more so $(2)$ holds. Rereadingwhat we just did, we see that we must ensure that $R\ge 3$ and $R\ge \frac5\epsilon$.

Hence with the choice
$$R=\max\left\{3,\frac5\epsilon\right\} $$
we have that $(2)$ holds for all $x>0$. This proofs the claim $81)$.$_\square$

---

Important points:

- Formulate the result you want to prove (even if you know the result only afterwards)
- Formulate what needs to actually be shown in order to prove the claim.
- Explicitly state any additional assumptions you make (such as $R\ge3$, $R\ge\frac5\epsilon$ here) in simplifying inequalities
- Beware of cases where the additional assumptions might contradict each other (if I had needed $R<3$ and $R\ge \frac3\epsilon$ instead ...)
- Actually show the claim. Finding a result vs. showing its correctness is usually a 180 degree turn, but if either of these two parts be left out at all, then the actual showing part better be left intact (of course, teachers request to *also* show the full finding process).
- In general, don't abhor textual fillings. A written "Therefore" or "From this and the original condition we conclude" or "For thsi it would be sufficient to have" tells the reader more than a simple logical connective $\Rightarrow$ or $\Leftrightarrow$, especially when the latter is more often then not left out or not justified or written in the plainly wrong direction.

Comment: I'm pretty happy until I got to the part where
10<5(x-1)^(2)
There's some "splitting" that come across as very arbitrary for a non-experienced student.

Comment: It's terribly wrong at that part.